# Conditional auto responder is Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have two versions of an auto responder that I would like to send out based on what the user selected from a dropdown field. So if the user selected California from the dropdown they would get autoresponder 1 and if the user selected Texas they would get auto responder 2. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly should be this code added?

## hook in to wpcf7_mail_sent - this will happen after form is submitted

add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' );

## our autoresponders function

function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {

```
    if( $contact_form->id==1234 ){ #your contact form ID - you can find this in contact form 7 settings

        #retrieve the details of the form/post
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();                          

        #set autoresponders based on dropdown choice            
        switch( $posted_data['location'] ){ #your dropdown menu field name
            case 'California':
            $msg="California email body goes here";
            break;

            case 'Texas':
            $msg="Texas email body goes here";
            break;

        }

        #mail it to them
        mail( $posted_data['your-email'], 'Thanks for your enquiry', $msg );
    }
```

}

Comment: This worked for me but I was tripped up because my checkbox input was returning an array. I got around that issue like this: $posted_data['my-checkbox-field'][0]

Answer (score 0):

Add in functions.php -

```
#hook in to wpcf7_mail_sent - this will happen after form is submitted
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' ); 

#our autoresponders function
function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {

        if( $contact_form->id==1234 ){ #your contact form ID - you can find this in contact form 7 settings

            #retrieve the details of the form/post
            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();                          

            #set autoresponders based on dropdown choice            
            switch( $posted_data['location'] ){ #your dropdown menu field name
                case 'California':
                $msg="California email body goes here";
                break;

                case 'Texas':
                $msg="Texas email body goes here";
                break;

            }

            #mail it to them
            mail( $posted_data['your-email'], 'Thanks for your enquiry', $msg );
        }

}
```

Comment: If I wanted to output html in the message how can this be done?